# How to print every element of a vector in a new line in R?

Tags: r, printing

I have a vector with numbers in it:
x = (1,2,...,n).

```
print(x)
```

Output:

```
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

I would like to print this vector, but every element in a new row. 
Desired output:

```
[1] 1
[2] 2
[3] 3
...
```

How can I achieve this? I cannot figure it out.

(This type of output is very common for Hackerrank challenges.)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `for(i in x) print(i)`

Comment: `sapply(x, print)`, which is a shortcut for `for(i in 1:length(x)) print(x[i])`

Comment: `cat(x, sep = "\n")`

Answer (score 3):

All of the suggestions print the values in a column but do not match the desired output since they do not include the index value of each element. The easiest way to do that is to convert to a matrix:

```
t(t(x))
#       [,1]
#  [1,]    1
#  [2,]    2
#  [3,]    3
#  [4,]    4
#  [5,]    5
#  [6,]    6
#  [7,]    7
#  [8,]    8
#  [9,]    9
# [10,]   10
```

Or less cryptically

```
matrix(x, length(x))
```

These do not match exactly either, but they preserve the original index value. If you really need to eliminate the , in the brackets, this will do it:

```
y <- data.frame(x)
rownames(y) <- paste0("[", 1:10, "]")
y
#       x
# [1]   1
# [2]   2
# [3]   3
# [4]   4
# [5]   5
# [6]   6
# [7]   7
# [8]   8
# [9]   9
# [10] 10
```